# How to configure properly unit testing with Errbot?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, plugins, errbot

I tried to follow this guide http://errbot.io/en/latest/user_guide/plugin_development/testing.html

I installed `pytest` and launch it with

```
pytest --rootdir='./srv/plugins'
```

but I have this following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./errbot/app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/errbot/backends/graphic.py", line 19, in <module>
    from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit
ImportError: No module named 'PySide'
2018-06-11 16:30:44,930 CRITICAL errbot.backends.graphic    To install graphic support use:
    pip install errbot[graphic]
```

It looks like `pytest` tries to run Errbot in graphical mode whereas I am using Errbot with a text backend just fine.

As the plugins might need at some point to use the configuration file given to Errbot, I wonder how to do the same while using `pytest`...

I reproduce on the host the arboresence found on a [Docker image](https://github.com/rroemhild/docker-errbot)

```
errbot
    app
        venv
        config.py
        requirements.txt
    srv
        data
        errbackends
        plugins
            Samples
                samples.plug
                samples.py
    run.sh
```

Then, I run `errbot` with a my backend - in my case Mattermost - like this:

```
./run.sh -c ./app/config.py
```

And for the `text` as backend

```
./run.sh -c ./app/config.py --text
```

In `run.sh`, I inject some environment variables and activate `venv` before calling `errbot`.

Actually, I could reproduce my issue on the unit testing by launching `errbot` in graphical mode

```
./run.sh -c ./app/config.py --graphic
```

Therefore, I wonder how to inject the right config for the unit tests as I can do while running `errbot`.

Comment: What do you have in /srv/plugins ?

Comment: @gbin: I have my plugins